# Get a service container name in workflow step

Tags: docker, github-actions

My general question is: how to get a running service name in Github workflow?

I have a Keycloak containerset up ass a service and I want to import a realm by executing a script inside Keycloak container, here is a snippet of my workflow:

```
name: Test Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4
        env:
            KEYCLOAK_USER: "admin"
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: "admin"
            JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled"
        ports:
            - "8091:8080"
        volumes:
            - "/workspace/src/main/resources/keycloak:/src/main/resources/keycloak/"

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 14

      - name: List running containers
        run: docker ps -a

      - name: Setup Keycloak realm
        run: |
            docker exec -it keycloak sh -c 
            "/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin && 
            /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=testrealm -s enabled=true && 
            /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create partialImport -r testrealm -s ifResourceExists=SKIP -o -f /src/main/resources/keycloak/realm.json"

      - name: Gradle Test
        run: ./gradlew test

[...]
```

To connect to a running container, I need its name. A service name `keycloak` doesn't work as I see in logs of Github actions a list of running containers:

```
Run docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
fdb7e1e05296   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4            "/opt/jboss/tools/do…"   55 seconds ago       Up 47 seconds       8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->8080/tcp   594297e586cd4bdab13cc8fa63b8954d_quayiokeycloakkeycloak1104_1ac754
```

Is there a way to connect to a running container via running container name?

Comment: In services, can you use the `hostname` directive to set a hostname ?

Comment: Can You explain what You mean?

Comment: In the `services` directive, you set the image used and other stuff. Can you try to set the hostname using `hostname: a name` like you would on docker ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. You set the `--name` in the service object options:

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    ...
    
    services:
      keycloak:
        ...

        options: --name keycloak --hostname keycloak
```

[Possible docker create options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#options).

[Workflow syntax documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idoptions).

2. According to this [example](https://github.com/actions/example-services/blob/main/.github/workflows/postgres-service.yml), the key of your service object can be used as the `hostname`. But this seems to be only relevant when running jobs from within containers.